# Loop through rows to get value of dynamically generated inputs

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, dom

I am using PHP, JSP and JSON for this code. I have to get values of my textboxes so I can insert them into my database.

I have a table that holds a siblings information, of course we have differrent number of siblings so I created a table that dynamically adds row and columns with textboxes on button click.

Here is the HTML code for table:

```
<table id="tbSibling">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Occupation and Employer</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtSib10" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtSib11" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtSib12" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtSib13" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onclick="insertSibRow();">Add</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

And he script that dynamically adds row and columns with textboxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Dynamically create rows and columns for Table Id: tbSiblings
    function insertSibRow(){
        var table=document.getElementById("tbSibling");
        var lastRow=table.rows.length - 1;
        var row=table.insertRow(lastRow);

        for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            var cellName=row.insertCell(i);
            var input=document.createElement('input'); 
            input.type='text';
            input.id='txtSib' + lastRow + i ;
            cellName.appendChild(input);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I give each input an id by:

```
input.id='txtSib' + lastRow + i ;
//result: txtSib10, txtSib11, txtSib12, txtSib13
```

Now I need to get each value so I can pass them on PHP page and insert each on the database.

But it only gets the first row, I get the last row so I can determine the number of rows.
and created an array so I can just push the values from it.

```
var lastRow=tblSiblings.rows.length;
var arrSiblings = new array();

for(x=0;x>lastRow;x++){
    arrSiblings[x] = $("#txtSib10").val();
}
```

Now my problem is this line:

```
arrSiblings[x] = $("#txtSib10").val();
```

How can I get each value of textbox from a dynamically created rows and columns??

Anyone?PLEASE HELP! THANKS A LOT.

Comment: Why not give them a class so you can use `$(".classname").each()`?

Comment: an easier way would be to use jQuery's [serialization](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) just give your inputs descriptive names and use [] to define each as an array, i.e: `siblings[0][name]`

Comment: @koala_dev, How can I accessed each row then?

Comment: you need to traverse the columns also right? or are you looking to extract only the value of input field with id `txtSib10`?

Comment: You have multiple 'td's (inputs) in a row, but you're looping through rows, shouldn't you be looping through columns of each row instead?

Comment: can you explain how you are sending the values to the database? I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using

Comment: no @Harry, I was just stuck there.. I need to extract all the value from each textbox of each row of the table

Comment: @koala_dev that is [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp)

Comment: well make sure it's properly formatted

Answer (score 5):

This is how I normally handle this type of dynamically generated rows of inputs.
I start with my form and name all my inputs as a single multi-dimensional array, with an index (starting with 0) and the name of the data they represent, in your case something like `siblings[0][name]` for your first input:

**HTML**

```
<table id="tbSibling">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="siblings[0][name]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="siblings[0][age]" /></td>
        <td>
            <select name="siblings[0][gender]">
                <option>Male</option>
                <option>Female</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="siblings[0][occupation]" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add-row" type="button">Add row</button>
```

Now to add a new row, I duplicate the last one in the table and clear all the input values and update the index in their name attribute, something like:

**JS**

```
$('#add-row').click(function(){
    var newRow = $('#tbSibling tbody tr').last().clone().appendTo($('#tbSibling tbody'));
    var newIndex  = newRow.index();
    newRow.find(':input').each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/, newIndex));
    });
});
```

In your case it looks like you're using ajax to send the data to your server so I would use jQuery's `$.post()` like this:

```
$.post('myphpfile.php',$('#tbSibling :input').serialize());
```

Now in your PHP you would have all your data in an array under `$_POST['siblings']` that you can loop and store in your database

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $siblings_data = isset($_POST['siblings']) ? $_POST['siblings'] : array();
    foreach($siblings_data as $sibling){
         $name = $sibling['name'];
         $age = $sibling['age'];
         $gender = $sibling['gender'];
         $occupation = $sibling['occupation'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be like :

```
for(x=0, y=1; x<4; x++){
    arrSiblings[x] = $("#txtSib" + y + x).val();
}
```

Comment: please try: arrSiblings[x] = document.getElementById("txtSib" + x).value;

Comment: Ops! sorry! got it now.. 'arrSiblings[x] = $("#txtSib" + y + x).val();' thanks!!

Comment: Shouold be for(x=0, y=1; x<4; x++)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#txtSib10").val()`

ID's are unique: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.id

"The ID must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the element using getElementById."

Change your script that generates the markup to use a class name, then grab the value for each generated text box within a loop.

Since the object you are building contains data for name, age, phone number and occupation, I would recommend adding a class name to each row, looping over that, then building the JSON:

```
$('.sib-row').each(function() {
  $_siblingsInfo = '{":RELATIONSHIP":"'+"Siblings"+'",":NAME":"'+$(this).find(".name").val()+'",":AGE":"'+$(this).find(".age").val()+'",":TEL_NO":"'+$(this).find(".telno").val()+'",":OCCUPATION":"'+$(this).find(".occupation").val()+'"}';
});
```

Assign a class name that can be used for the text fields in every row so that when looping over them the same code can be used:

```
<table id="tbSibling">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Gender</th>
  <th>Occupation and Employer</th>
  <tr class="sib-row">
    <td><input type="text" class="name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="age" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="telno" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="occupation" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onclick="insertSibRow();">Add</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```