# Best practice in adding form row

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms

I have a working form with a javascript 'Add Row' button, data collection and processing by PHP.  While it works, the code seems fairly high-maintenance and clumsy to me (for one thing, every time I change the form I need to work the same changes into the js that adds the new row).  I'm looking for suggestions to make it more sleek and simple.  Currently I'm assigning each input a unique name, with hidden input that keeps track of the number of rows for me, and then I use that number to determine the amount of `for` loops the PHP script needs to work through to post to the database.

One thing I've considered is changing from input names to using name[], but I'm not sure if that's the right method for my needs, and how I post each row as a separate record to the database.  In any case, here's the code.

**HTML**

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr style="display: none"><td colspan="2">
        <input type="hidden" id="samp_count" name="samp_counter" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" value="sample" name="type1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td >pic caption </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text"  name="desc1"/></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td >extended description</td>
    <td><textarea style="width:100%" rows="7" name="notes1"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>pic file</td>
    <td><input id="pic_file1" type="file" name="pic1" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="add_row" width="40px" id="samp_add_button">add row
```

**JavaScript** for the button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#samp_count").val("1");
    $("#samp_add_button").click(function(){
        var iter_str=$("#samp_count").val();
        var pic_id = "#pic_file" + iter_str;
        if (!$(pic_id).val()){
            $("#samp_error").css("visibility","visible");
        }
        else{
                iter_str ++; // update counter
            $("#samp_count").val(iter_str); //reset counter in table header to current count
            var a = '<tr><td colspan="2" ><span>pic caption<input type="text"  name="desc'+iter_str+'"/></span><br /></td>";
            var b = '<td rowspan="3">extended description<br /><textarea style="width:100%" rows="7" name="notes'+iter_str+'"></textarea></td>';
            var c = '<tr><td colspan="2" >pic file</td><td><input id="pic_file'+iter_str+'" type="file" name="pic'+iter_str+'" /></td></tr>';
            $("#table1").append(a+b+c);
            $("#samp_error").css("visibility","hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send_button'])&&$isValid==TRUE){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $count_str1 = $_POST['samp_counter'];
    $count1 = intval($count_str1);
    for ($i=1; $i <= $count1; $i++) { 
        $desc= "desc".$i;
        $pic= "pic".$i;
        $notes= "notes".$i;
        $desc_con = $_POST[$desc];
        $notes_con = $_POST[$notes];
        if($_FILES[$pic]["name"]){
            if( formFileUpload($pic, $user)){   //custom function to validate and upload pics-- not relevant to question at hand
                  $uid_path = "portfolios/".$user."/";
                  $file_path=$uid_path.$_FILES[$pic]["name"];
                  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'admin','pass');
                  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);
                  $statement=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO portfolios (UserID, Description,  FilePath, FileType,  Notes) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
                  $statement->bindParam(1,$user);   
                  $statement->bindParam(2,$desc_con);
                  $statement->bindParam(3,$file_path);
                  $statement->bindParam(4,$_POST[type1]);
                  $statement->bindParam(5,$notes_con);
                  $statement->execute();

            }
                else{
            $fileErrorDis="inline";
            $isValid=FALSE;
            } }}
?>
```

[Link to working website](http://www.soferim.org/signup_form3.php) -- self-explanatory but text in Hebrew (in some of the forms, the js has not been updated and the new row does not resemble the original one)

Comment: Here's an answer I posted on a related question about how I normally handle this kind of dynamic rows of inputs http://stackoverflow.com/a/17937976/2049063, basically you can use a foreach and avoid the need of the count field and clone an existing row instead of manually creating a new one with the same structure

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! I +1 your answer there, since you didn't post one here (and indeed it seems superfluous).  Is there anything else I need to know in order to deal with the file upload, or does it pretty much work the same way as the other inputs? (I currently have no trouble with the uploads--I know how to do it the long way. My question is regarding file objects contained in an array.)

Comment: To be honest I've never had to work with file inputs in this way, my guess is it will work the same, you'd just need to define the complete name for the input when accessing the `$_FILES` array, i.e: `$_FILES['items[0][pic]']`, if that doesn't work then I'd suggest you do a `var_dump($_FILES)` to look at the structure of the array and change the code accordingly

Comment: OK, great. Thanks for the prompt reply!